# Proxy(Wiremock) for Feign Client

Tags: java, spring, wiremock, netflix-feign

We are using feign client for communication between our microservices.

We would like to have the possibility to record and mock communication between our backend and some external middle tier services. - That would be for our remote servers not for tests.

Is there such a possibility or you guys have some different ideas?

Comment: Inevitably the answer will be either "Yes", or "It depends". WireMock is not specifically a test tool, but is often used in that context. I'm not entirely sure what you mean with " .. would be for our remote servers not test." Given that this is the key to your question can you elaborate on that by updating the question?